# Blockchain API, AJAX request has stopped working, CORS issues?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been playing with the multiple address look up API from blockchain info (documented here https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_api), I had my code working earlier in the day but bizzarely it's stopped.

The purpose of it is to eventually write a little JQuery library which will search the DOM for bitcoin addresses as data attributes and then insert the final balance into that element creating a polling mechanism to keep the page updated as well.

The original problem I ran into earlier while developing it was because it's a CORS ajax request but later I adjusted the query per the blockchain info API documents and I added cors=true it then seemed to work fine but now it doesn't seem to want to work at all again. I don't get how changing computers would effect this kind of request.

Here's my code on JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/SlyFoxy12/9mr7L/7/

My primary code is:

```
     (function ($) {

        var methods = {
            init: function(data, options) {
                //put your init logic here.
            },
            query_addresses: function(addresses) {
                var addresses_implode = addresses.join("|");

                $.getJSON("http://blockchain.info/multiaddr?cors=true&active="+addresses_implode, function( data ) {
                    $.each( data.addresses, function( index ) {
                        $('#output').append(" "+data.addresses[index].final_balance);
                    });
                });
            }
        };

        $.fn.bitstrap = function () {
            var addresses = new Array();

            $('[data-xbt-address]').each(function () {
                $(this).text($(this).data('xbtAddress'));
                addresses.push($(this).data('xbtAddress'));
            });

            methods.query_addresses(addresses);
        }

    }(jQuery));

    $().ready(function() {
        $().bitstrap();
    });
```

Comment: Why don't you log the parameter passed to the function in $.each and see if there is data being returned. There is no way to tell what your error is without additional info.

Comment: I know for a fact that the function of the getJSON call isn't even being fired so there's no point, plus you can put alerts in to show where it's not firing

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out it's an issue with Chrome some how, I've tried it in safari and it works again, it must have been a different version of Chrome on the other computer I used.

There seems to be more info about it here https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104920